# How to use a specific version of System.Globalization?

Tags: c#, mscorlib

I have a UWP app that uses `Microsoft.NetCore.UWP` as a dependency.

I want to use `System.Globalization` library, but the one included in `mscorlib`, not the one included in NetCore.

That is because the latter has several additional methods I need, f. e. `CultureInfo.GetCultures(...)`.

How do I use it? 
Right now my `using System.Globalization` point to this file:

```
#region Assembly System.Globalization, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=...
// C:\Users\...\.nuget\packages\system.globalization\4.3.0\ref\netcore50\System.Globalization.dll
#endregion
```

What I need is this:

```
#region Assembly mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=...
// C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll
#endregion
```

Comment: Editing the packages.config of your project to change the version of your System.Globalization reference should work.

Comment: @Lennart How could I do that in order to use mscorlib, not globalization dll?

Comment: I've searched on the internet and have found that the mscorlib version is linked to the .NET framework version you're using in your project. So by changing the .NET framework version you can get a different mscorlib version. Haven't verified this myself but I think there's no other option than to either: change your code so you are compatible with a newer .NET framework version; or select a different .NET framework version for your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K, after some investigation...

You can use the .net standard 2.0 compatible version of `System.Globalization` in your project to allow calling `CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)` but, first you need to make sure you are targeting the 
***Fall creator's update version**

#### My application properties

[image: What I currently have installed]

Once you have updated that then install the package from nuget.

### My nuget packages installed

[image: The min version of UWP]

Once I've done that the following runs fine.

`var testresult = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);`

Comment: Thanks! But where can I get a Fall Creators Update?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028685/windows-10-get-the-update